# check from preprocessor if -mint8 is used for compilation

Tags: c-preprocessor, avr, avr-gcc

Is there any c macro predefined if compiler option `-mint8` is in use?

Background:

I can compile something for avr with the -mint8 compiler option which results in smaller code size. That violates against the c standard, but this is not the problem here.

I simply want to

```
#ifdef MINT8  // search the name for the macro here
  ...
#endif
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `int_least8_t` or `int_fast8_t` isn't being used instead?

Comment: Sometimes you can not control which type is used "internally". E.g. bit fields will generated as int internally. Access of bit fields will result without -mint8 in 2 byte access which is much overhead sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVR Libc tests the value of `__INT_MAX__`:

```
#if __INT_MAX__ == 127
 ...
#endif
```

If you include `<stdint.h>` then it will define `__USING_MINT8` as 0 or 1 as appropriate.